# checked out file not visible in clearcase view?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I created this new clearcase element and checked out but when I try to check in, it is giving an error saying "no such file or directory". I can see this file checked out in an activity so how can I get this file check in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to debug this is through a shell

```
cd /path/to/parent/directory/of/the/file
cleartool ls
```

Look for the version and selection rule for that file.

Check also the config spec of your view

```
cleartool catcs
# or
cleartool edcs
```

See if the config spec does start with a:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
```

---

For a "`checked out but removed`" status, you can refer to "[How to recover a file from “`Checkout but removed`” state?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11740244/6309)".
The idea is to "undo checkout" a dummy file (same name, but empty), in order to recover it as *before* any local change.
There is no easy way to recover the local changes done  while that file was ched out and present (except for some file recovery tool like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), but it is a long shot).

Comment: I see the file is checked out and removed. Is there a way to recover it?

Comment: @user not that I know of. You can erase it with a dummy file with the same name (and no content): that would allow to *undo* checkout, getting back that file *before* any local change.